# Can geth be run in batch?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using PoA and running geth just from the cli on google cloud. But I found I had the error below. In terms of reliability is there a way to run it without a dependence on ssh (eg something like batch)?

> INFO [04-13|13:41:00] Commit new mining work
>   number=2178 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=206.317µs INFO [04-13|13:41:00] 
>   block reached canonical chain          number=2172 hash=f4ced7…b74e50
>   INFO [04-13|13:41:05] Successfully sealed new block
>   number=2178 hash=43ec93…e99f5a INFO [04-13|13:41:05]  mined
>   potential block                  number=2178 hash=43ec93…e99f5a INFO
>   [04-13|13:41:05] Commit new mining work                   number=2179
>   txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.588ms packet_write_wait: Connection to
>   35.195.116.27 port 22: Broken pipe ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]. ~/blockchain$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope, I understand your question right: you want to run geth in background, so it is not terminated when your ssh session closes?

If yes, and you're using Linux, you can:

1. use `screen` (see https://kb.iu.edu/d/acuy)
2. Start geth in background with `nohup geth .... &`